# AWS Cloud9 instance huge drop in performance when Chrome tab not open

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, multiprocessing, aws-cloud9

I'm currently running a batch processing script through AWS Cloud9. The script is running on 48 cores on a c5.12xlarge EC2 instance. Performance is good, as long as the tab is active. If I leave the tab for an extended period of time, the performance drops of a cliff.

Has anyone else experienced a similar problem and worked out a fix?

Thanks!

Comment: On [this thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=307896) they recommend using cloud9 terminal and run your command with `nohup` in order to keep the process running for a long time. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying that out now

Comment: This seems to be working nicely.  Running "$ nohup python my_script.py &" in cloud 9. EC2 CPU usage now up to 90% for a consistent period of time

Comment: Glad to hear it worked :)

Comment: Really appreciate the help, thanks